# how to use the global variable in a class component in React-native project

Tags: react-native, logging, components, global

i'm using a global variable that is declared in a `app.tsx` as a `functional component` like

```
const App = () => {
useEffect(r => global.some = 'anything')
}
```

i'm using this global variable in other `functional component` very vell like this

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
useEffect(r => console.log(some)) //annything
}
```

but when i using this in a `class component` i gives me an error called `unexpected token`

like

```
class NewClass extends React.Component {
useEffect(r => console.log(some) //error : unexpected token 
}
```

do someone has the answer what is going wrong what should i have to do to to log the data

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` belongs to react hooks and `hooks only works with a functional component`, `not with class component`.

According to docs.

**Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8. They let you use state and other React features without writing a class**

[Link to docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Edit: Hooks are basically a replacement of lifecycle methods in functional component, Before `16.8` we can't use lifecycle methods inside the functional component hooks made possible this for us in `16.8` version of react.

Now coming back to your question if you are doing something in functional component and wanted to do class component for the same logic you have to use lifecycle methods which since until now hooks are not available in-class component.

**There is nothing that you can do with hooks and can't do with classes and vise versa.**

As your comment, you have achieved the same thing with componentWillUpdate
but this method is gone a deprecate from `v17 of react` so if you wanted to do something while component updates you have to use componentDidUpdate is the recommended way.
here is a list that how hooks represent lifecycle methods.

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/lifecycle-methods-substitute-with-react-hooks-b173073052a

Comment: i understand that but i'm not using any hooks

Comment: i'm just using the variable which declared globally

Comment: Could you make a snack for it ?

Comment: sorry to say but it was revoked and i'm currently using useEffect very well in a class component

Comment: no i  can't but this is a private project. but we can connect on anydesk

Comment: useEffect is confusing in your code if it's a hook imported from 'react' then surely you can't use it inside class component but if you defined function or variable with this name then please avoid using these words.

Comment: I am not asking for complete code I was just saying to create a snack with the code you posted here with the issue reproducible manner.

Comment: sorry i fund the soluion the solution was putting them into the componentWillUpdate function but gives me another trouble and the trouble is it firing the data multiple times? likely 4 times in a row

Comment: Let me update the Answer for you I got it what you wanted to do.